# como saber si un string es un char, int, double?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas queria hacer un metodo que funcionara para validar si un string es de tpo double, int, char.

tengo este método

```
public static boolean esReal(String cadena) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

nose si lo ideal sería meter todo en un mismo método hacer 3 métodos diferentes, de cualquiera de las dos formas conocen algún tipo de variable como parseInt para verificar double y datos de tipo char

tenia este codigo para evaluar el tipo double pero no me funciona nose porque

```
public static boolean esReal(String cadena) {
    try {
        Double.parseDouble(cadena);
        
        return true;
        
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Olvide mencionar que tu **esReal** funciona, quizás te hayas confundido porque le pasaste un int o Integer y devolvió true, pero eso es correcto, no olvides que en un sentido, java castea automáticamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con lo que tienes, estás verificando si el tipo de dato de `cadena` es entero, si no lo es, ocurre la excepción:

```
Integer.parseInt(cadena);
```

Para saber si es decimal, sería:

```
Double.parseDouble(cadena);
```

Y para saber si es de tipo char (caracter):

```
cadena.length() == 1;
```

Ahora, la idea es si tenerlo en 3 métodos diferentes o todo en uno solo, yo lo vería mejor tenerlo todo en uno solo, separando cada validación en un bloque `try`, quedando así:

```
public static String validarTipoDato(String cadena) {
    try {
        Integer.parseInt(cadena);
        return "entero";
    } catch (NumberFormatException e1) {
        try {
            Double.parseDouble(cadena);
            return "decimal";
        } catch (NumberFormatException e2) {
            if (cadena.length() == 1) {
                return "caracter";
            } else {
                return "No válido";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias me funciono

Answer (score 1):

Una mejor alternativa podría ser utilizar un [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). Aprovechas sus funciones `has...` y te evitas las excepciones.

Por ejemplo, con `double`:

```
public static boolean isDouble(String str) {
    var scanner = new Scanner(str);
    return scanner.hasNextDouble();
}
```

O con `int`:

```
public static boolean isInt(String str) {
    var scanner = new Scanner(str);
    return scanner.hasNextInt();
}
```

Puedes hacerlo de forma similar para cada tipo primitivo.

---

En cuanto a la otra pregunta, es mejor usar 3 funciones separadas ya que mejora la legibilidad.

Es posible que quieras obtener un `String` con el nombre del tipo. Podrías escribirla de forma conveniente usando las otras funciones.

Por ejemplo:

```
public static String checkType(String str) {
    if (isInt(str))
        return "int";
    if (isDouble(str))
        return "double";
    // ...
}
```

Quizá sea mejor devolver un enum en lugar de cadenas.

Incluso podrías devolver un diccionario con una clave por cada tipo primitivo y asociada a un booleano que te diga si se puede convertir o no.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte

Answer (score 0):

Solo por mostrar otro camino...

```
String queEs( String numero ) {
  int largo = numero.length();
  if( numero.matches( "[\\d]+" )) {
     return "entero";
  }
  if( numero.matches( "[\\d]{1,}(.){1}[\\d]{1,}" )) { 
     return "decimal";
  }
  if( largo == 1 ) {
     return "char";
  }
  else {
     return "otra cosa";
  }
}
```

Es importante el orden de las evaluaciones, ya que un entero es también un decimal, y por otro lado, "3" se puede interpretar como "char".
Hay que tener en cuenta que este método tiene sus "cosas", por ejemplo, si se ingresa la cadena "2543543543", nos va a decir que es un entero... y lo es, pero si queremos crear un int a partir de el, nos lanzará un error.

Comment: muchas gracias por tu aporte